# how to solve error when deleting 'view' in the onClick method?

Tags: android, kotlin

so I set the method name when the button is clicked like this:

[image]

and the in the activity class I set `loginButtonTapped` method like this:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnTouchListener  {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    }

    fun loginButtonTapped(view: View) {

    }

}
```

and in the build tab, I have warning, it is said that parameter view is never used:

[image]

yes I never used the view arg on that `loginButtonTapped`

and then I try to delete that parameter to be  `fun loginButtonTapped() {}`

but it even worse, I got crash when I run the app:

> Process: com.xxxx.lakuinkotlin, PID: 10922
>           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method loginButtonTapped(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for
>   android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id
>   'login_button_loginActivity'

so how to avoid that 'Parameter view is never used' and also free from crash ? what went wrong in here?

Comment: The warning is not fixable, since the parameter View is mandatory by Android SDK, even if you don't use it. About the crash, can you please show the View XML definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way that XML and Java code interact in Android.
You must have the view as the function parameter in order to have the instance of the clicked view.

You can try one of the following:

- Ignore the lint checking by **suppressing it** (Press the yellow light bulb).
- Use `.setOnClickListener()` method of view and *pass a no param function in the implementation of the Listener* `onClick(View)`.

```
TextView t;
t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         onClickTextData(); // No param
     }
});
```

- Use [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library.

```
//All arguments to the listener method are optional.

@OnClick(R.id.submit)
public void submit() {
  // TODO submits data to server...
}
```

Because the method is called without getting the Button in onCreate. And in order to access that Button, you need to have a view.
So to avoid the crash you must add the View instance to the method.

As you can see you have `Could not find method loginButtonTapped(View)` in the error text. Meaning that this way of implementing `onClick` needs a function with a `view` as a parameter.

Comment: You only answered half of the question.

Comment: His function already has View as parameter `fun loginButtonTapped(view: View)`...

Comment: He's saying when I **don't have it**, I get crash, and when I `have it` I get a warning.